# RXjava2 subscribeOn(Schedulers.()) is not working

Tags: java, rx-java2

I am new to `rxjava`. I have Simple subscriber define like below for file processing. 
This is working fine.

```
observable.subscribe(                         
                      data -> System.out.println(data)
                      Throwable::printStackTrace,
                      () -> log.info("File Processing Completed")
                     );
```

But When i am trying to use `Schedulers` like below it's not working. I am not receiving any Exception or error.

```
observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
          .subscribe(
                   data -> System.out.println(data)
                   Throwable::printStackTrace,
                   () -> log.info("File Processing Completed")
                  );
```

is anything wrong in my config ?

Comment: Do you run it in a unittest and not waiting for the new thread to process anything?

Comment: No, I have spring boot application and ruining it using Application class. i am expecting some thread is in logs . but logs does not show only Main thread

Comment: you may want to post the context, there is nothing wrong with the snippet you posted.